# Add ID or similar to class in jquery-function?

Tags: javascript

I have 20 buttons on same page which opens different images with onClick. Buttons use same styling and are div-class.Each button is made out of 2 absolute positioned buttons which changes position by display none / block when clicked. For this I'm using jQuery.

Problem is that I only want the jQuery-function to work on the button clicked and not the 19 other buttons at the same time. Can name or ID or other solution solve this?

Here's the code:

```
$(function(){
  $('.zoom_In').click(function(){
    $(".zoom_Out").css({"display":"block"});
  });
});

$(function(){
  $('.zoom_Out').click(function(){
    $(".zoom_Out").css({"display":"none"});
  });
});
```

```
.links {
    float: left;
    width: 88%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 4%;
    border: 2px solid #900;
    background: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer; 
    text-align: left;

    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #999;
}
#zoomBtn_wrap  {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 28%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 20% 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.zoom_In {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #CCC;
    cursor: pointer;

    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 100%;
}
.zoom_In:hover  {
    border: 2px solid #999;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
.zoom_Out {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #CCC;
    cursor: pointer;

    display: none;

    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 100%;
}
.zoom_Out:hover  {
    border: 2px solid #999;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
```

```
<div class="links"> 
      <div id="zoomBtn_wrap">
          <input name="" type="button" id="" class="zoom_In" onClick="" title="" value="Show" />

           <input name="" type="button" id="" class="zoom_Out" onClick="" title="" value="Hide" />                
      </div> <!--End of zoomBtn_wrap-->
</div>

<div class="links">                
      <div id="zoomBtn_wrap">
                <input name="" type="button" id="" class="zoom_In" onClick="" title="" value="Show" />

                 <input name="" type="button" id="" class="zoom_Out" onClick="" title="" value="Hide" />                
      </div> <!--End of zoomBtn_wrap-->
</div>
```

Comment: `this` will refer to the current element inside the event handler. I recommend to read the [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me:_Using_selectors_and_events).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.zoom_In').click(function(){
    $(this).next().css({"display":"block"}); // Show the button next to the clicked button.
  });
  $('.zoom_Out').click(function(){
    $(this).css({"display":"none"}); // Hide the clicked button.
  });
});
```

**[Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/nrPp6/1/)**

Also, there's no need to wrap both listener assignments in a separate `$(function(){});`

Comment: But i can see where you want to go with it

Comment: @KennethHayes, what's not working about it? What does it do that it shouldn't, ot doesn't do what it should?

Comment: The solution breaks the fuctionality of original code: changing display of "zoom_Out" - if you can test posted code youll see what i mean. But thx anyway for posting

Comment: Sorry Cerbrus - your current solution is 100% correct! Im new on the forum - getting a little confused - but you saved my day - thx again

Comment: Ah, that's okay :P I'm glad to be of help. Thank for accepting my answer!

Comment: Do you know how to automatically hide all "zoom_Out" when a "zoom_In" is clicked? Could it have something to do with sieblings? Cant make it work -

Comment: To hide _all_ `"zoom_Out"` when `"zoom_In"` is clicked: `$('.zoom_In').click(function(){$('.zoom_Out').css({"display":"none"});});`

Comment: Sorry - all except for the one clicked of course - my mistake.

Comment: `$('.zoom_In').click(function(){
$('.zoom_Out').css({"display":"none"});
$(this).css({"display":"block"});
});`

Comment: Cerbrus - you are amazing! Thx once again

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` keyword:

```
$(function(){
  $('.zoom_Out').click(function(){
    $(this).css({"display":"none"});
  });
});
```

I assume this is what you want to achieve.

P.S.

You can also use jQuery's built in show/hide methods to help yourself out (write shorter code). Like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.zoom_Out').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a javascript function  inline  to your html  or use `this` operator in such a way that:

```
$(function(){
  $('.zoom_In').click(function(){
    $(this).css({"display":"block"});
  });
});

$(function(){
  $('.zoom_Out').click(function(){
    $(this).css({"display":"none"});
  });
});
```

Comment: Your first function shouldn't apply to `this`

Comment: Thx for all answers but after testing none works. I think question is misunderstood - the $(this) solution looks right but the first function must do 2 things at same time: 1. change display of "zoom-out" from none to block + 2. only select one pair of all buttons on page